# Using relative/abs references to insert a function using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some formulas I am attempting to insert into my worksheet through the use of VBA. The rows are dynamic. Whether I attempt to insert the formula with a standard formula or R1C1, part of the formula changes the relative references where I need but not on another.

```
Range("B25:B" & LastRow).Formula = 
"=IFERROR(IF(ISTEXT(E$21),AVERAGEIF(BottomLeftTable[Billing 
Name],$A25,BottomLeftTable[Margin]),""""),"""")"
```

This causes the istext portion to evaluate only E21 when it should be E21 in B25, F21 in B26, G21 in B27, etc. What I find weird is the inserted formula will actually change the $A25 as needed. It places A25 in B25, A26 in B26, A27 in B26, etc.

From what I've read, VBA does not allow R1C1 functions to change the reference so ultimately my question is can the standard insert formula work to paste the formulas where I need them while changing the reference as the formula fills down rows and if so, how to go about doing so? Thank you!

Comment: `E21 in B25, F21 in B26, G21 in B27` - the pattern you want is neither absolute nor relative - you are wanting to change the source cell by one **column** for every **row** that the destination cell changes by

Comment: My apologies. Is there a term for this then? I've only ever referred to it as relative and absolute since making references of these types generally change the cell reference when using auto fill.

Comment: I think the appropriate term for this would be "nightmare".  Unless you set up a loop to insert each cell's formula (using the loop counter to work out the appropriate source column based on the destination row), your only other options would be to use the `INDIRECT`, `OFFSET`, or `TRANSPOSE` Excel functions to determine the source cell.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I'll look into these additional possibilities.

Comment: i tried this `Range("B1:B10").Formula = "=$a" & (1 + 1)
` and it worked as expected. it is possible that _BottomLeftTable_ is moving between iterations.  put the two _BottomLeftTable_ values  into variables and put the variables into the formula instead of the _BottomLeftTable_ functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, here is a loop that would individually set the formula in each cell:

```
Dim r As Long
For r = 25 To lastRow
    Cells(r, "B").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(ISTEXT(" & Cells(21, r - 20).Address & _
                            "),AVERAGEIF(BottomLeftTable[Billing Name],$A" & r & _
                            ",BottomLeftTable[Margin]),""""),"""")"
Next r
```

Comment: A loop is good enough for me and it worked like a charm! I'll still brush up on the other formulas you mentioned as I've seen them used a bit but don't personally use them enough to use them wisely. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Craig I also don't use those Excel functions enough to have made an easy answer out of them, which is why I answered with a loop option :D